# Going from an MFCC coefficient to Hz range?

Tags: frequency-domain, mfcc, conversion

I have not worked with MFCCs before, but I am faced with the observation that the 5th MFCC of a signal is actually of interest for me in my speech research. In order to understand why that one is important for me, I need to make sure that I understand what it represents.

If I know the number of Mel frequency spaced filters applied to the signal, and the sample rate, can I assume that the 5th coefficient is related to the 5th mel spaced filtered regions?

If not, how do I learn what in the frequency domain is represented by the 5th MFCC?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding you need a little more information.
You need to know the minimum and maximum frequency and number of coefficients in  the MFCC representation.

If the coefficients are linearly spaced in the [mel scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_scale), $m(f)$

The first coefficient is $m(f_1)$ the last coefficient is $m(f_N)$, and the $i-$th coefficient is

$$m(f_i) = m(f_1) + \frac{i-1}{N-1} (m(f_N) - m(f_1))$$

Then you replace apply the definition of interest for $m(f)$, e.g.

$$m(f) = \frac{1000}{log(2)}log\left(1 + \frac{f}{1000}\right) $$

And solve for $f_i$.